# Refreshing the activities that are present in the back stack

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, actionbarsherlock

I have a **Enter you details** option on the action bar as an action item and I am setting that option visible on all activities by extending the below class.

```
   public abstract class ActionActivity extends SherlockActivity {
        protected boolean mIsEnterDetailsScreen = true;
        protected userName = "";
        SessionManager session;

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

             if(mIsEnterDetailsScreen)
             {
                 menu.add("Enter Your Details")
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
             }

             else 
             {
                 menu.add(userName)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
             }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            //This uses the imported MenuItem from ActionBarSherlock
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {

            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActionActivity.this,EnterDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                  session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

            sessionCheck();  // This method's body is separated for the easiness and pasted below.

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }

        }
```

So, by the above code, if the user enters details, I am saving it in preferences and at the same time setting the `mIsEnterDetailsScreen = false;` so that this option would be invisible and user name taken from his entered details would be visible. This works fine only for the activities that are started later. But not on the previous activities. So, my doubt is how to refresh the activities that are there in the back stack. So that even when he presses the back button, still the **`username`** has to be displayed even in the previous activities after he entered details instead of **Enter you details** option.

Suppose if user clicks the **Enter you details** action item on the 3 rd activity, the changes reflect in the later activities(4, 5, 6....), but not on 1st activity and 2nd activity. Is there any way to refresh activities so that the changes persist.

This is the sessionCheck() method in ActionActivity

```
 public void sessionCheck()
     {
         if(session.isLoggedIn())
         {
             mIsEnterDetailsScreen = false;

             HashMap<String, String> userHashMap = session.getUserDetails();

             // name
             String name = userHashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_USER_NAME);


             userName = name;
         }

         else{

             mIsEnterDetailsScreen = true;


         }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user enters details, save them somewhere persistent, I would suggest using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  Then override `onResume` in your Activities that will be in the backstack and load the details (from the `SharedPreferences` for example) there.

Android does not use an `onRefresh` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using SharedPreferences only as I also mentioned in question. I want the changes to be reflected even on the present activity too. Can you please suggest?

Comment: To show the changes in the options menu of the previously created Activities, you'll have to use `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.  You can reuse what you have in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the example, except you'll have to load the username from preferences since you won't have the private variable in the previous Activities.

Comment: +1 for your time. I have edited my question with extra code. Can you please check it now and suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to implement the override method onRefresh on the first activity.

While you close come back from Details Activity or you close/finish the Second Activity(that is your Enter Your Details Activity), onRefresh method of the First activity is called. At that time you can set the Value from the SharedPreference. So, that way you can get the Values reflacted on your view.

Hope you got my point.
Feel free for any comments.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I want the changes even reflect on the present activity too.

Comment: yes you can. Just Create onRefresh Method on the previous activity. Put code to toast any message. now just run your app and check. You will get that toast display while you come back from the next activity to previous activity. Hope you got the point.